# 'module' object has no attribute 'PY2'

Tags: 14.04, django

I am using ubuntu 14.04, was trying to install python-memcache. I have got an error like

```
Downloading/unpacking python-memcached
  Downloading python-memcached-1.53.tar.gz
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 292, in run_egg_info
    logger.notify('Running setup.py (path:%s) egg_info for package %s' % (self.setup_py, self.name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 284, in setup_py
    if six.PY2 and isinstance(setup_py, six.text_type):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PY2'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/mani/.pip/pip.log
```

I am getting the same error when installing Django-celery, pymongo etc

Answer (score 1):

The Python module six that is installed is very old. Within your python interpreter

```
import six
six.__version__
```

The current version is 1.7.3, on my 12.10 Ubuntu system  the default was 1.1.0. Upgrade this module and you will be up and running again.